# Nodejs variables that persist per express session

Tags: node.js, express

I have some information that is unique to each user, this information does not change often so I have setup a cronjob using `node-cron` to update the value once a day.

My question is: Where can I store this value?

I tried `app.locals` but from what I see it acts as a global variable for the whole application meaning all the users then have the same value in this variable.

I also tried using `res.locals` which works perfectly, but only for the first page load which is where it is being set. After that when I reload the page, the variable is undefined because it is only being set once.

The way I am doing this:
I have a middleware in my code which checks if the cronjob has been scheduled. If not, then it schedules the cronjob and also runs the code once to get the value and then set it to res.locals which is why it works on first load. When I reload, this middleware can see that the variable was already set before so it goes straight to the next middleware or route using the `next()` function.

The way that I check if a cronjob is set currently is also wrong because of the same issue. Right now I have a global variable `cronSchedule` which is a boolean. The problem is that it's app scope variable so when the first user loads the page, the variable is set to true so the cronjob will not take place for the other users.

My Middleware

```
app.use( function( req, res, next ) {
  if (!cronScheduled) {
    // schedule tasks to be run on the server   
    cron.schedule('0 0 * * *', function() {
      functionToGetData();
    });
    functionToGetData();
  } else {
    next();
  }
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just managed to figure this out!

Using `req.session` I managed to accomplish this.

Here is my updated middleware:

```
app.use( function( req, res, next ) {
  if ( req.user !== undefined && !req.session.cronIsScheduled) {
    // schedule tasks to be run on the server   
    cron.schedule('0 0 * * *', function() {
      functionToGetData();
    });

    functionToGetData();
  } else {
    next();
  }
} );
```

And I added an additional piece of code which adds this value from the session to `res.locals`

```
app.use( function( req, res, next ) {
  res.locals = {
    user: req.user !== undefined ? req.user : undefined,
    academic_periods_student: req.session.academic_periods_student
  };
  next();
});
```

Now this variable is unique to each user and it is not reset on each page load. It also resets when a user logs out and back in which in my case is a bonus!